# Why can a lambda for collections.defaultdict have no arguments?

Tags: python, lambda

In python I have the following line of code:

```
my_var = collections.defaultdict(lambda: collections.defaultdict(collections.defaultdict(float)))
```

I don't understand what it is doing. One of the things I don't understand is how we have not specified any variables for the lambda function.

Comment: Because the factory function does not accept any arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *`default_factory`* argument to `defaultdict` should be a function that doesn't accept any arguments which creates and returns an object which will become the value of any non-existent entries that get referenced.

One way to provide such a function is to create an anonymous one using an inline [`lambda` expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions). Another way is to use the name of a built-in function the creates and returns one of the built-in types, like `float`, `int`, `tuple`, etc. When any of *those* are called without an argument, the value of the object returned will have some default value — typically something like zero or empty.

First of all, you can make code like you have more readable by formatting it like this:

```
my_var = collections.defaultdict(
            lambda: collections.defaultdict(
                collections.defaultdict(float)))
```

However, (in either form) it's incorrect, since some of the `defaultdict` calls don't have callable function arguments. Because Python is an interpreted language you won't know this until you try to use `my_var`. For example something like:

```
my_var['level1']['level2']['level3'] = 42.
```

would result in:

```
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

This can be fixed by adding another `lambda`:

```
my_var = collections.defaultdict(
            lambda: collections.defaultdict(
                lambda: collections.defaultdict(float)))  # need lambda here, too
```

and afterwards the preceding assignment will won't be considered an error.

Since `defaultdict` is a subclass of the built-in `dict` class, you can use the `json` module to pretty-print instances of one:

```
import collections

my_var = collections.defaultdict(
            lambda: collections.defaultdict(
                lambda: collections.defaultdict(float)))

import json  # for pretty printing dictionaries

# Auto-creates the 3 levels of dictionaries needed.
my_var['level1']['level2']['level3A'] = 42.

# Similar to above but additionally auto-creates a
# my_var['level1']['level2']['level3B'] entry with default value of 0.0
my_var['level1']['level2']['level3C'] = my_var['level1']['level2']['level3B'] + 1

print(json.dumps(my_var, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2": {
            "level3A": 42.0, 
            "level3B": 0.0, 
            "level3C": 1.0
        }
    }
}
```

I think you should be able to understand what it does now — but let me know if not.